# Inequality for regular function

Tags: analysis

Let $ u \in C_0^{\infty}( \mathbb{R}^N),\ N \geq 2. $ Is it true that $$ \left|u(x)\right| \leq c \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} \frac{\left| \nabla u (y)\right|}{\left|x-y\right|^{N-1}},\ \forall\ x \in \mathbb{R}^N? $$ where $  c $ is a constant.

Comment: I wrote that, for all $ y \neq x, $ we have $$ u(x) = \int_{- \infty}^1 \frac{d}{dt} u(y + t(x-y)) dt = \int_{-\infty}^1 \nabla u(y + t(x-y)) (x-y) dt. $$ I do not know if we can continue like this?

Comment: I get it. If we continue like this and integrate $ y $ over the ball $ B(x,1), $ we can get the result.